# Does this inequality involving inverse tangent (arctan) hold?

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

I am wondering if the following statement is true for $\theta\in\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$:

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)+x}{\cos(\theta)+y}\right)\leq\theta+x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)+c(x^2+y^2),$$

where $c\geq2$ is a constant (though an answer showing that constant $c$ exists without quantifying what it is would be good enough).

I've plotted the difference between RHS and LHS for multiple values of $\theta$ and the inequality *seems* to hold.  However, I have no idea how to prove this, as my usual method of Taylor series expansion (around $(x,y)=(0,0)$ does not seem to work here (the series converges only for $|x|,|y|<1$).  Can anyone help?

If the above inequality holds, I think that it would solve [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220544/variance-computed-using-taylor-series-does-not-agree-with-numerical-experiment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

I will prove that $c$ must be arbitrarily large in the case $x=0$, $y=-k$, and $\theta=-\frac{\pi}{2}+k$.

In this case, we want

$$\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(-\frac{\pi}{2}+k)}{\cos(-\frac{\pi}{2}+k)-k}\right)\leq-\frac{\pi}{2}+k-(-k)\sin(-\frac{\pi}{2}+k)+c(k^2)$$

which is equivalent to

$$\frac{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(k)}{\sin(k)-k}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}-k+k\cos(k)}{k^2}\leq c,$$

so it is sufficient to show that the LHS can be made arbitrarily large.

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow0^+}{\frac{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(k)}{\sin(k)-k}\right)+\frac{\pi}{2}-k+k\cos(k)}{k^2}}=\lim_{k\rightarrow0^+}{\frac{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(k)}{\sin(k)-k}\right)}{k^2}},$$

and the limit of the numerator is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ while the limit of the denominator is 0, so

$$\lim_{k\rightarrow0^+}{\frac{-\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(k)}{\sin(k)-k}\right)}{k^2}}=\infty.$$

Comment: Very nice answer.  Looks like the trouble comes from the limiting behavior of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\cos(k)}{\sin(k)-k}\right)$ at $k=0$: if the limit is taken from the left, it is $\pi/2$; if it is taken from the right, it is $-\pi/2$.  I gotta think a bit more about my approach for the motivating question in http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/220544/variance-computed-using-taylor-series-does-not-agree-with-numerical-experiment  Thanks for your help!

Comment: I posted a follow-up question here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1843251/inequality-involving-inverse-tangent-arctan