# Inequality involving inverse tangent (arctan)

Tags: trigonometry, inequality

Suppose $-\frac{\pi}{2}+\epsilon\leq\theta\leq\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon$ for some $\epsilon>0$ and $x,y\in\mathbb{R}$.  I am wondering whether there exists $\delta>0$ such that:

$$\left|\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)+x}{\cos(\theta)+y}\right)-\theta\right|\leq \left\{\begin{array}{ll}f(x,y)&~\text{if}~|x|,|y|\leq\delta\\c_2+f(x,y)&\text{otherwise}\end{array}\right.,$$

where $f(x,y)=|x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)+c(x^2+y^2)|$ and $c_1,c_2\geq0$ are constants.

Basically, I am wondering does there exist a small region around the origin where the error in approximating $|\theta|\leq\frac{\pi}{2}-\epsilon$ from the noisy in-phase and quadrature components $\sin(\theta)+x$ and $\cos(\theta)+y$ such that it 1) is governed by $f(x,y)$ if $(x,y)$ is in that region; and 2) is governed by a constant plus $f(x,y)$ everywhere else.

The two-dimensional Taylor series expansion of $\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{\sin(\theta)+x}{\cos(\theta)+y}\right)$ can be used to show that the first assertion is true, since $f(x,y)$ is essentially the first term (linear) and the remainder (quadratic) in this expansion, and it converges for $|x|,|y|$ small enough.

I am having trouble with the second assertion.  It *seems* true by inspections of the plots, with $c_2\leq\pi$. Unfortunately, I have no idea how to prove this.  Can anyone help?

This is related to my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1839562/does-this-inequality-involving-inverse-tangent-arctan-hold).

Comment: Have you tried reformulating the problem in terms of polar coordinates? $f(r,\theta)=\vert r\cos(2\theta)+c r^2\vert$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Yes, except that I couldn't figure out what to do with the LHS.

Comment: Yes, it would be nice if that denominator were $\cos\theta-y$, then the LHS would equal $\vert\tan^{-1}r\vert$.

Comment: $\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\tan A+\tan B}{1-\tan A\tan B}\right)=A+B$
so$\tan^{-1}\left(\dfrac{\tan\theta+r}{1-r\tan\theta}\right)=\tan^{-1}\left( \dfrac{ \tan \theta+\tan(\tan^{-1}r)}{1-\tan\theta\tan(\tan^{-1} r)}\right)=\theta+\tan^{-1}( r)$, then $\theta$ is subtracted.

Comment: Had a devil of a time getting that formatted right. Whew!

Comment: Actually replacing every $\theta$ with $-\theta$ would accomplish the same thing if that even would make sense in the underlying problem.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Actually, I am now confused about your first comment: I don't see how $x\cos(\theta)-y\sin(\theta)=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\cos(2\theta)$...

Comment: Let $x=r\cos\theta,\,y=r\sin\theta$, then $x\cos\theta-y\sin\theta=r\cos^2\theta-r\sin^2\theta=r\cos2\theta$.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales Ahh, but $\theta$ is *not* the angle induced by $(x,y)$ represented as a complex number $x+yi$.  The representation of $f(x,y)$ that I have is $f(r,\phi)=|r\cos(\theta+\phi)+cr^2$ where $\phi=\tan^{-1}(y/x)$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$...  That being said, trigonometric transformations might be a way to go here...  I'm playing with them right now.

Comment: Ok, I just realized that the second assertion is trivially true for $c_2=\pi$ since the range of $\tan^{-1}(z)$ is $\left(-\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$...